# Hotline Miami savegame compatibility Win:OSX

Tags: hotline-miami

The save directory structure under my OSX and Windows copy of Hotline Miami (from Steam) differs: OSX have a text `saves.dat`, while Windows have a binary `SaveData.sav` (though many parts are just text, similar to the other file).

Am I supposed to figure it out with an hex editor, or is there a script to convert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem is not win:osx, but original:updated version

[FAQ on Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219150/discussions/0/846963711058351091/):

> *Can I use my progress from the original version in the updated version?*
>
> Yes, **if savedata.sav doesn't exist, the original save game is
>   imported**. To reimport, remove savedata.sav from the save directory.